# Help improve my question, or move to StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, stackoverflow

I'm seriously considering making a registry change in Windows that could impact a considerable number of all Windows users, which possibly would affect PCs either supported by, or using software installed by members of both SuperUser and StackOverflow.

My post: [Prevent message: “A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly”, globally?](https://superuser.com/questions/935212/prevent-message-a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-internet-explorer-to-run-slow)  Is asking if my registry change would affect anyone's PC they take care of, or any software they are involved in creating or supporting.  Yet, I haven't received any answers or comments, and now have one down vote.

I really need your advice on how to get the answers to confirm my decision before I make this change.  Although I don't think there would be problems, this really could potentially impact other members negatively.  I'm happy to do whatever is required, including removing it, asking to move it to StackOverflow, or elsewhere than any StackExchange site.

EDIT:  I did just now change the question title to:  **Would this registry change affect you or your users negatively?** This is hopefully closer to the real question I'm seeking, although it won't include any information about my proposed change in the title.

Comment: I left some questions in a comment on the question, but I'm having trouble making sense of the question.  It almost looks like you're asking about a change to the registry on your PC affecting other people.  If that's the case, it only affects your computer.

Comment: This registry change would be made to anyone that installs our software, which possibly could affect many millions of users.  It appears I'll just make this change, since no one seems care about this issue.   I see very few questions from any software or hardware companies, who usually make unilateral decisions, and then wonder why users are complaining.  I'm asking for advice first, rather than assuming I know what's best.  I really wish other OEMs would validate some of their decisions here before deploying them. @fixer1234, I also replied and clarified in the question's comments.

Comment: That's exactly what alpha and beta tests are for. Do those before a mass rollout. And be prepared to fix and issues. Save the registry before you install your program and be prepared to back out the change if your users complain.

Comment: "Although we could handle the error" - why don't you handle it then? That's much better than blindly changing the registry of millions of PCs. If MS thought the correct thing to do was to make that change they would have done it already.

Answer (score 1):

This question won't be accepted on SO.

You should focus on improving your question so that we can follow your train of thought and everything is properly organized in their own paragraphs.

Comment: I'd welcome any suggestion where you think that issues like this could be put out for public review before we or any OEM, makes a unilateral decision that will affect millions of users.  Although it might not fit here in SU or on SO, I do think questions like this need to be posted somewhere.

Comment: @DaaBoss As an OEM you should be having this whole discussion with Microsoft.